# Check value in two lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to implement a function to check whether some  values are the same in two lists.
For example, win([1,2,3,4,5]). win([2,3,4,5,6].
Now I want to compare [2,3,4,5,10] with above one by one. If there is 4 elements are the same, then it will have further action. I know member() can use for exact match but dont know how to do the matching with part of them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution.

Comment: Maybe `findall(X, (member(X, L1), member(X, L2)), Samesies)`?